# Find values in a file from another file

Tags: grep, diff

I have 2 files, in one of this I have some values and I need to find them in another file. Instead to grep for each single value, I would use the first file to do lookup in the second file

i.e.

File 1

```
ns1.cloudns.net. -17554 IN A 85.159.233.17
ns1.cloudns.net. -17554 IN AAAA 2a00:1768:1001:9::1
www.alweya.com. -335336 IN A 192.69.217.246
```

File 2

```
alweya.com
```

Outout - File 1 contains `www.alweya.com`

Comment: What are you wanting as output?  Do you want to know where each value is the the other file?  Do you just want to know if it exists?  Do you want a count of the occurrences?

Comment: What is the format of these values? A word per line? Values with spaces?

Comment: I'll give you an example
File1
a
b
c
d
e
File2
1
x
a
5
e

Result that I'm looking for: In file 2 there are "a and e"

Thanks!!

Comment: @Federi [edit] your question add more information, please. Use code formatting for your example files.

Comment: Not really intereste about the format. I need just to know if the value are present in the second file and if yes, which one. Then guys, give me your best solution. Will be very interesting, I know!

Comment: So your files have the patterns as a comma separated list on a single line?

Comment: That is the format

File 1
ns1.cloudns.net. -17554 IN A 85.159.233.17
ns1.cloudns.net. -17554 IN AAAA 2a00:1768:1001:9::1
www.azimage.com. -335336 IN A 192.69.217.246

File 2
alweya.com

Comment: As previously pointed out, please edit your question instead of adding new information here.

Comment: do you want to search file1 for patterns in file2, or search file2 for patterns in file1?  your sample output is only possible the first way (`alweya.com` is in both files, but `www.alweya.com.` is only in file1): `grep -F -f file2 file1`

Answer (score 1):

```
while read line
do
msg="File 1 contains "
msg2="$msg$(grep "$line" file1.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
if [ ${#msg2} -ne ${#msg} ]; then
  echo $msg2
fi
done < file2.txt
```

File 1

```
ns1.cloudns.net. -17554 IN A 85.159.233.17
ns1.cloudns.net. -17554 IN AAAA 2a00:1768:1001:9::1
www.alweya.com. -335336 IN A 192.69.217.246
```

File 2

```
alweya.com
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you want to do. The simplest approach is to use `grep`, passing a file of patterns with `-f`:

```
$ grep -f file2 file1 
www.alweya.com. -335336 IN A 192.69.217.246
```

If you need to control the output in more detail, you can use a shell loop:

```
$ while read pat; do 
    grep -q "$pat" file1 && echo "file1 contains $pat"; 
done < file2
file1 contains alweya.com
```

The second approach lets you print individual messages for each pattern found but will be much, much slower on larger files.